# Get aspect ratio video from network is incorrect in Ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I used video_player package to play video from network. In android, everything is okay. But in ios, both aspect ratio of video, width and height seem to get incorrect.
How to get correct aspect ratio of video?
Thank in advance!